# Javascript Embedded Image Resources

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, custom-controls, embedded-resource

I am currently using embedded resources within a custom control. I have images embedded which are icons for navigation etc. However I need to be able to use these images within the embedded JavaScript to change the images depending on certain criteria.

I know how to access embedded resources within c# asp.net pages, but not however within JavaScript.

I have tried the following with no success.

```
document.getElementById('button1').src = "NAMESPACE.FOLDER/DIRECTORY.IMAGE.png";
```

I don't believe the JavaScript I have written is wrong, just how the image is accessed.

I am not interested in alternatives with CSS /  C# code because it has to be done with JS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual path to your project is defined, try to access the image file with a slash before the src.

If it is not defined, do the following to define your project's virtual path (I suppose you are working with *Visual Studio*):

1. click on your project name (not the solution).
2. in the properties window, change the virtual path property to `"/"`.

Comment: Yes I am using visual studio. I will try this and see if it works.

Comment: In visual studio 2010 I am unable to find / define the projects virtual path. I was hoping to use some thing like this within the javascript. document.getElementById('button').src = '<%=WebResource("MyNameSpace.MyImagesFolder.TEST.png")%>';